# Am I reading the C99 grammar correctly?

Tags: c99

I was reading through the [language syntax summary](http://www.dii.uchile.cl/~daespino/files/Iso_C_1999_definition.pdf#page=414) in the C99 standard and I noticed that the grammar seemed to permit declaring functions without parentheses.

Like this:

```c
int main
{
}
```

But when I test this with gcc I get a syntax error.

Am I reading the C99 grammar wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which exact part of the grammar led you to believe this? Also, C is a bit more context-sensitive. There are verbal texts which may add to the grammar.

Comment: The definition of a ```function-definition``` which contains a ```declarator``` which contains a ```direct-declarator``` which seems to show that a function definition could be declared without parentheses. Hope that makes sense?